# Dense subset of the conjugate space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

The question is:

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $B$ be a dense subset of $X^*$(the conjugate space of $X$). If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is bounded, and if $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for each $x^*\in B$, then prove that $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for each $x^*\in X^*$.

Could anyone tell me the way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: it suffices to show that $x^*(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: $|x^*(x_n)-x^*(x_m)|\le |x^*(x_n)-x^*_k(x_n)|+|x^*_k(x_n)-x^*_k(x_m)|+|x^*_k(x_m)-x^*(x_m)|$?

Comment: Basically yes. But then you need to specify how you choose your $k$, and how large $n,m$ have to be.